# Notifying of PHP errors

Tags: php, rest, debugging, report

I developed a REST API in PHP. Is there any way I can get alerted when a PHP script has a fatal error? Ideally I'd like to get an email with the error that occurred.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792394/how-to-email-php-fatal-errors-only :)

Comment: Well, fatal kind of implies not much else is going to happen ....

Comment: @BartFriederichs It does, but not in PHP. `register_shutdown_function()` + `error_get_last()` can be used to log / mail fatal errors. Also many of the previously fatal errors have become exceptions in PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks, got it working!